# rest call from node fails

Tags: node.js, debugging, networking, express

I am building a node.js/express app which makes remote calls to other internal web application (ASP.NET WEB API) to consume json from it. We are in a corporate network. Here is the strange issue.

On my Mac OSX (Mavericks), I can curl from shell and get json from `http://our_internal_host:9991/connections`. I can also type this URL and see the JSON response from the browser.

When I run this express app locally and request the route which makes the remote call, I see this error on the console. The route handler logs this message below and browser hangs.

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect' }
```

Node process cannot make a connection to that address. I also have a Windows 7 machine at work and I do not encounter this issue on my Windows 7 machine. When I run the same node app on Windows 7, I don't have any issues.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot the issue...

PS: A colleague of mine who has the same setup doesn't have this issue. We compared DNS configs but our setup looks to be same.

**Any pointers to troubleshoot this issue is much appreciated. I know this is environment specific issue but not sure where to start.**

Thanks

EDIT #1

Route handler making the remote call which logs the error above...

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'our_internal_host',
  port: 9991,
  path: '/analytics'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
    // removed response code
    console.log(res);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Did you try curl'ing the url from the system your express app is running on to verify it is reachable? If you can verify it, can you post the code you're using to do the request?

Comment: I can curl and get data in shell. I'll post the code shortly.

Comment: Is there a proxy server involved?

Comment: Yes, we have a corporate proxy. The ethernet connection has the proxy settings in place. The shell also has the http_proxy and https_proxy variables exported from bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my Mac's IP was on a different subnet than other machines.